# Android: Buttons in compound control interfering with ListView's ContextMenu

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-listview, textview, android-button

The problem I've been having here is that the 2 buttons in the list item xml seems to be interfering with the ContextMenu in the main activity, preventing it from inflating when a list item is long-pressed. Just as a note, the buttons themselves work fine. When I removed them, the ContextMenu works perfectly.

The list item xml:

```
<com.anna.mytallykeeper.views.TallyItemView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/item_description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="40px"
    android:textColor="@color/dijon" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/decrement_button"
        android:layout_width="80px"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/minus_button_1" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/increment_button"
        android:layout_width="80px"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/add_button_1" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/increment_button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/decrement_button"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="80px"
        android:textColor="@color/dijon" />
</RelativeLayout>
</com.anna.mytallykeeper.views.TallyItemView>
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/piplup">
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

From the main activity (inherits from ListActivity):

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    app = (MyTallyKeeperApplication) getApplication();
    adapter = new TallyItemListAdapter(this, app.getTallyItems());
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    Utility.logI((getListView() == null ?
            "ListView is null" : "ListView is not null"));
    Utility.logI((getListView().getId() ==
            android.R.id.list ? "ListView ID is correct" :"ListView ID is not correct"));
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}
//
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)     
{
    Utility.logI(MyTallyKeeperMain.class.getSimpleName() + ".onCreateContextMenu");
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    if (v.getId() == android.R.id.list) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.item_menu, menu);
    }
}
```

From the list adapter class (inherits from BaseAdapter):

```
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    TallyItemView tiv;
    if (view == null) {
        tiv = (TallyItemView)View.inflate(context, R.layout.tally_item_row, null);
    } else {
        tiv = (TallyItemView)view;
    }
    tiv.setTallyItem(tallyItems.get(position));
    tiv.getDecrementButton().setOnClickListener(new DecrementListener(position));
    tiv.getIncrementButton().setOnClickListener(new IncrementListener(position));

    return tiv;
}
```

Comment: means u want to open the context menu on button click?

Comment: on long-pressing the list item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out how to fix the issue with the buttons interfering with the ContextMenu: set each button's focusable attribute to false.

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/increment_button"
        android:layout_width="80px"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/add_button_1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done with list view onClick

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> view, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long id) {

                openContextMenu(arg1);
```

and for long click

```
 registerForContextMenu(list);
```

for more details http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/fe5691bf03af949c

Thank you.

Comment: I just tried doing this, but no luck. The problem with my app, I think, is that each ListItem contains buttons.

Comment: I finally figured out what was wrong with it. Thanks for the advice anyway.